# Raspberry Pi 3 Python for PN532 I2C

Tags: python, i2c, nfc

I've looked everywhere however have no idea on how to write a python program to listen to PN532 via I2C? Only SPI libraries however I cannot use that.

Comment: A quick google search turned this up https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2012/12/14/nfc-on-raspberrypi-with-pn532-py532lib-and-i2c

Comment: [Adafruit's writeup](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-nfc-rfid-on-raspberry-pi/overview) uses UART rather than SPI or I2C. Not exactly what you're after, but possibly worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Setting up a PN532 NFC module on a Raspberry Pi using I2C](https://blog.stigok.com/2017/10/12/setting-up-a-pn532-nfc-module-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-i2c.html) to set up PN532 on Raspberry Pi. Then, you can see the link shared by Steve Robillard, [NFC on RaspberryPi with PN532, py532lib and i2c](https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/blog/2012/12/14/nfc-on-raspberrypi-with-pn532-py532lib-and-i2c), to read one tag using the PN532 via I2C.